# How to align this expression at the plus sign

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, split

I'm trying to split this expression into two parts and I want to align the minus sign right below the plus sign. However if I type:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^{t}_{H} &\bigg\{ \, A_{p,t}(1 \, - \, \eta) \, 
log(C_{H,t} \, - \, \eta C_{H,t-1}) \, +  \, j A_{j,t} A_{p,t} \, 
log(H_{H,t}) \, - &  \\
& - \, \frac{\tau}{1+\chi^{H}} \Big[ \, \big(  \, 
(N_{H,t}^c)^{1+\kappa_{H}^N} + (N_{H,t}^h)^{1+\kappa_{H}^N} \big)^{ 
\frac{1+\chi^{H}}{1+\kappa_{H}^N}} \, \Big]  \,  \bigg\} 
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I have tried it with `align`, `align*` etc. but nothing solved the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Note: use `\log` instead of `log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes no real sense, it is still outside the margin. However, you'll see in my example how it can be aligned and, of course, do *not* use all those `\,`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^{t}_{H} \bigg\{  A_{p,t}(1 - \eta) 
log(C_{H,t}  -  \eta C_{H,t-1})  &+   j A_{j,t} A_{p,t} log(H_{H,t})  \\
& -  \frac{\tau}{1+\chi^{H}} \Big[ \big(  
(N_{H,t}^c)^{1+\kappa_{H}^N} + (N_{H,t}^h)^{1+\kappa_{H}^N} \big)^{\frac{1+\chi^{H}}
    {1+\kappa_{H}^N}}  \Big]  \bigg\} 
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

I prefer in such a case `multline`:

```
\begin{multline}
E_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^{t}_{H} \bigg\{  A_{p,t}(1 - \eta) 
log(C_{H,t}  -  \eta C_{H,t-1})  +   j A_{j,t} A_{p,t} log(H_{H,t})  \\
 -  \frac{\tau}{1+\chi^{H}} \Big[ \big(  
(N_{H,t}^c)^{1+\kappa_{H}^N} + (N_{H,t}^h)^{1+\kappa_{H}^N} \big)^{\frac{1+\chi^{H}}
    {1+\kappa_{H}^N}}  \Big]  \bigg\} 
\end{multline}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks Herbert! That solved the problem!

Comment: You could use `\log` for a nicer appearance.

Comment: Yes, that is true ...