# How to indent each line after a fraction in a single expression?

Tags: formatting, fractions

[image]

[image]

How can I format the fractions to appear underneath like so in both images. For the second image the plus should not be under the expression above it.

Here is my code for the second image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}} +  \\
        \phantom{\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}}} +  \\
        \phantom{\frac{\frac{1}{27}}{1 - \frac{1}{3}}} \\
        \phantom{.} \\
        \phantom{.} \\
        \phantom{.} \\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The output appears like so:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can see e.g. [beamer - How to align the plus sign under 1? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540537/how-to-align-the-plus-sign-under-1/540565) and adapt to your case. Or [equations - How to align this expression at the plus sign - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377378/how-to-align-this-expression-at-the-plus-sign)

Comment: The site guidelines recommend waiting a few hours, and maybe even a day or more, before "accepting" an answer you find particularly useful. For by quickly accepting the very first answer that's been posted, you are basically discouraging others from providing additional, potentially even better, answers.

Comment: Sorry about that, haven't been on the stack for a while so i've forgotten how we operate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an `array`-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \addlinespace macro
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\frac13 + \frac29 + \frac3{27} + \frac4{81} + \frac5{243} + \cdots 
\begin{array}[t]{ *{6}{NC} }
=& \frac13 & + & \frac19 & + & \frac1{27} & + & \frac1{81} & + & \frac1{243} & + & \cdots \\ \addlinespace
 && + & \frac19 & + & \frac1{27} & + & \frac1{81} & + & \frac1{243} & + & \cdots \\ \addlinespace
 &&&& + & \frac1{27} & + & \frac1{81} & + & \frac1{243} & + & \cdots \\ \addlinespace
 &&&&&& + & \frac1{81} & + & \frac1{243} & + & \cdots
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose this simple solution with the `alignedat` environment:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \[
    \frac13 + \frac29 + \frac3{27} + \frac4{81} + \frac5{243} + \cdots =
    \begin{alignedat}[t]{5}
     \frac13 &+ \frac19 & & + \frac1{27} & & + \frac1{81} & & + \frac1{243} & & + \cdots \\[1ex]
      &+ \frac19 & & +\frac1{27} & &+ \frac1{81} & & + \frac1{243} & & + \cdots \\[1ex]
     &&& + \frac1{27} & & +\frac1{81}& & + \frac1{243} & & +\cdots \\[1ex]
     &&&&&+ \frac1{81} & & +\frac1{243} & &+ \cdots \\[1ex]
     &&&&&&& +\frac1{243} & &+ \cdots
    \end{alignedat}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got your question right. I set an equal sign at each line, you might have to change it if it isn`t the desired choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{9} + \frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{81} + \frac{5}{243} + ... \\
        = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{81} + \frac{5}{243} + ... \\
        = \phantom{\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{81} + \frac{5}{243} + ... \\
        = \phantom{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9}} + \frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{81} + \frac{5}{243} + ... \\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As another user mentioned, you can use the `\phantom{...}` as a placeholder for the number you want to hide. Otherwise you can use the `&` sign in the `align` environment to set the desired lines aligned.
[image: result]

The secont problem should work the same. If it is a matrix you might use a matrix environment described [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Matrices).

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: The last two lines should not start with `=`. All numerators in rows 2, 3, 4 etc should be `1`. Do write `\cdots` instead of `...` in order to generate the appropriate typographic ellipses.